# ASP.NET Core Openiddict throws "An OpenID Connect response cannot be returned from this endpoint"

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I follow instruction in openiddict server example using password flow from https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/master/samples/PasswordFlow
but have no success.

It throws **InvalidOperationException: An OpenID Connect response cannot be returned from this endpoint** at route **/connect/token**:

`return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);`

Postman params:

- **Content-Type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- **Params:** username=..&password=...&grantType=password&scope=offline_access+profile+email

I spent my day for researching but there is no information about **cannot be returned from this endpoint** exception. And many people can run openiddict example except me.

Here is apart of Startup.cs:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
    .AddDbContext<MisapayContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseOpenIddict<int>();
    });

    //....

    services.AddOpenIddict<int>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<MisapayContext>()
    .DisableHttpsRequirement()
    .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
    .EnableLogoutEndpoint("/connect/logout")
    .EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/connect/userinfo")
    .UseJsonWebTokens()
    .AllowPasswordFlow()
    .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
    .AddEphemeralSigningKey();

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter());
}).AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
});
```

**Edited:** I think problem is **OpenIdConnectRequest**, it can not be binded if use:

`OpenIddictBuiler.AddMvcBinders()`

Will throws The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved from the ASP.NET context.`

Otherwise, remove it, OpenIdConnectRequest in AuthorizationController can get properly. And I can get request information such as username, password grantType etc... Strange... right?

Some other information:

- Asp.net Core SDK 1.1
- Project.json : https://gist.github.com/trinvh/47f29468887c209716098bc4c76181a7
- Startup.cs: https://gist.github.com/trinvh/75b7a12fbee754d0ea8cf251f2da9fe9
- AuthorizationController.cs: https://gist.github.com/trinvh/089015b2573cae550856631e72b81374

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you found out that the 'return SignIn()' throws this exception?

Comment: Did you also add the services.AddIdentity and services.AddOpenIddict<int>().AddMvcBinders() in the ServiceConfiguration and the necessary stuff in the Configure?

Comment: I tried run some example code from other's repos but sadly they not working too. I put breakpoint in return SignIn... so i sure exception throws here. Very strange, every body run fine but not me!

Comment: Yes i followed the instruction on repo's page. I get the code from other sources too but not work.

Comment: @trinvh please post your entire Startup class and your authorization controller.

Comment: I found a similar issue here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/252. Pinpoint probably has the answer ;-)

Comment: @Pinpoint I run the example that giving from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691207/net-core-webapi-openiddict-credentials-flow-and-angular2-client-401-after. Please look into

Comment: Please see the question again, I just edit it.

Comment: @trinvh I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing locally. Can you please share the exact HTTP request sent by Postman by clicking on the "code" button in Postman? (near the "Send" button)

Comment: Of couse, check it out https://gist.github.com/trinvh/3971c130fc2ee25dcb53f61f50e89c3f

Comment: @trinvh really strange. The only issue I see is that the `grant_type` parameter is misspelled (`grantType` vs `grant_type`). But in this case, you get a 400 response with `{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter was missing."
}`... not an exception. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: Yes i think grantType and grant_type is default json formatter. If i use grant_type i get the above resp. You can look at request param i attached in gist. Please read my answer i edited, if i use AddMvcBinders the endpoint will throws can not bind exception. Can you please try again with exact project.json i gave?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here's what's happening:

- You've configured OpenIddict to use `/connect/token` as the token endpoint address.
- The token request you send via Postman points to `/connect/token/`, which is actually a totally different URL (`/connect/token` != `/connect/token/`).
- Since the address differs from the registered endpoint path, OpenIddict doesn't handle the request and refuses to consider it as a token request.
- For some reasons, MVC accepts to handle your `/connect/token/` request and invokes the `Exchange` action, even though the route doesn't match the requested URL.
- Since you haven't registered the OpenIddict MVC binder in the MVC options, MVC uses its default binder to construct the `OpenIdConnectRequest` object, which allows the `OpenIdConnectRequest.GrantType` parameter to be resolved from the invalid `grantType` parameter (it wouldn't happen with the dedicated OpenIddict binder).
- Your token endpoint action ends up calling `SignIn` to return a token response.
- Under the hood, OpenIddict detects that you called `SignIn` outside the normal token request processing - since it didn't consider the request as a token request, due to the paths difference - and aborts this unsafe operation by throwing an `InvalidOperationException`.

I'll ping the MVC folks to make sure they are aware of this bug.

**Edit:** after some research, it looks like this behavior is "by design" and was inherited from ASP.NET MVC. I opened [a feature request in the aspnet/Mvc repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5757) to add a new way to use "strict comparison" for routes matching.

Comment: Im online mobile so i will check this later. Thank you so much!

Comment: @trinvh FYI, since MVC's behavior is very unlikely to change, I decided to update OpenIddict to use a relaxed URL comparison policy, that assimilates `/connect/token/` to `/connect/token`. Don't hesitate to give the latest OpenIddict bits a try.

Comment: Bravo @pinpoint, i'm following your issues you posted on MCV's repo. Thank for your hard work. Awesome !