# ASP.NET Core SignIn(Principal, Properties, AuthenticationScheme) is throwing An authorization or token response cannot be returned from this endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

The current follow of my application is that I'm getting access-token from the front-end then using that token my backend is calling the External-Login provider to conform the user identity and retrieve the extra information-from the login provider.

As in this method I have to setup and configure login provider for each client(web ,android ). I'm tryin to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook` in my back-end to handle the facebook login using the claims which I'm getting from facebook I want to use that to generate Openidic JWT token. Everything works fine but statement

`return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);`

is throwing an Exception

`An authorization or token response cannot be returned from this endpoint.`

here is the question with same error but context is different [ASP.NET Core Openiddict throws "An OpenID Connect response cannot be returned from this endpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42048770/5678666)

here is another question with similar approach but different [How to Generate AccessToken for user who is logged in with External Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44908344/5678666)

Here is my `startup.cs` code

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ApplicationDbContext"];

    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        opts =>
        {
            opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Repository"));
            opts.UseOpenIddict();
        }
    );

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.AppId = "APP_ID";
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = "APP_SECRET";
                facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;

            });

    var validIssuer = Configuration["Token:Issuer"];
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,

                ValidateIssuer = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(validIssuer),
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateActor = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
            };
        });

    services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
    {
        // Register the Entity Framework stores.
        options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        options.AddMvcBinders();
        options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/account/token");
        options.UseJsonWebTokens();
        options.AllowPasswordFlow();
        options.AllowCustomFlow("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:facebook_access_token");
        options.AllowCustomFlow("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:google_access_token");
        options.AllowCustomFlow("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:microsoft_access_token");
        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        options.AddSigningKey(securityKey);

    });


    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {

    //OpenId

        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;

        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });


    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter());
    });   

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This is the controller which is handling External-Login

```
   [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider = "Facebook", string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Auth", new { returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error from external provider");
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        if (info == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        try
        {
            var ticket = await _accountService.TokenExchangeAsync(info);
            return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.ServerError,
                ErrorDescription = ex.Message
            });
        }
    }
```

Here the code that handles creating user and other related stuff and it is called by `ExternalLoginCallback`

```
    public async Task<AuthenticationTicket> TokenExchangeAsync (ExternalLoginInfo info)
        {
            var claims = info.Principal.Claims;
            var profile = new Profile
            {
                email = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Value,
                id = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value,
                name = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value
            };

            // Find the user
            var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, profile.id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.email))
                    throw new Exception("Email is not specified in the user profile for the provider.");

                await RegisterExtenalUserAsync(profile, info.LoginProvider);

                /// Try to find the user
                user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, profile.id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    // Return bad request if the user doesn't exist
                    throw new Exception("Invalid profile or provider.");
                }
            }
            // Create the principal
            var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

            // Claims will not be associated with specific destinations by default, so we must indicate whether they should
            // be included or not in access and identity tokens.
            foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
            {
                // For this sample, just include all claims in all token types.
                // In reality, claims' destinations would probably differ by token type and depending on the scopes requested.
                claim.SetDestinations(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken, OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
            }

            // Create a new authentication ticket for the user's principal
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(),
               OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

  //  Include resources and scopes, as appropriate
          var scope = new[]
            {
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                    OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
            };

            ticket.SetScopes(scope);

            // Sign in the user
            return ticket;
        }
```

Here is the Log file

```
    Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult[1]
Project>       Executing SignInResult with authentication scheme (ASOS) and the following principal: System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.
Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult[1]
Project>       Executing SignInResult with authentication scheme (ASOS) and the following principal: System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.
Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
Project>       Executed action Project.Controllers.AuthController.ExternalLoginCallback (Project) in 9068.4071ms
Project> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
Project>       Executed action Project.Controllers.AuthController.ExternalLoginCallback (Project) in 9068.4071ms
Project> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Project>       Connection id "0HL86DQMN0Q30", Request id "0HL86DQMN0Q30:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Project> System.InvalidOperationException: An authorization or token response cannot be returned from this endpoint.
Project>    at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<SignInAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
Project> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @poke `SignIn` is a `ControllerBase` method and is one of the entry points of the ASP.NET Core authentication stack in MVC Core (the other ones are `SignOut`, `Challenge` and `Forbid`). Here, the OP is implementing an OIDC server using OpenIddict and implementing the logic in an authorization controller is indeed the recommended option.

Comment: @Pinpoint Ah, okay, didn’t realize this was a *server* and not an application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is actually really similar to [the second link you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908344/how-to-generate-accesstoken-for-user-who-is-logged-in-with-external-providers) and the exception you're seeing has the same root cause: you're trying to return a token response from an endpoint that is not considered as your token endpoint by OpenIddict (i.e the path of your `ExternalLoginCallback` action doesn't match the one set when calling `options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/path")`.

For security reasons, OpenIddict refuses to process such a response and throws an exception.

To fix that, you'll have to do 2 things:

#### Use code or implicit instead of the password flow

**The password flow can't be used with interactive authentication flows** that involves roundtrips to external providers like Facebook (you can see this flow as a simple API call that takes your username/password and returns a token).

Instead, consider using an interactive flow like code (for mobile apps) or implicit (for browser-based apps). You can find samples for these 2 flows here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples

For instance, to enable implicit flow support, you can do something like that:

```
// Register the OpenIddict services.
services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
{
    // Register the Entity Framework stores.
    options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
    // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
    // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
    options.AddMvcBinders();

    // Enable the authorization endpoint.
    options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize");

    // Enable implicit flow support.
    options.AllowImplicitFlow();

    // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

    // Register a new ephemeral key, that is discarded when the application
    // shuts down. Tokens signed using this key are automatically invalidated.
    // This method should only be used during development.
    options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
});
```

---

#### Move the `SignIn` logic to avoid calling it from endpoints that are not managed by OpenIddict

Since you can't call `SignIn` from `ExternalLoginCallback`, you'll have to move the `SignIn` call to your authorization endpoint action (in the OpenIddict samples, it's generally named `AuthorizationController.Authorize()`):

```
var ticket = await _accountService.TokenExchangeAsync(info);
return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Then, revert the changes made in your `ExternalLoginCallback` action so it simply redirects the user to your `Authorize` action when the FB login process is complete (don't forget that here, the `returnUrl` parameter represents the location of your authorization endpoint with the mandatory OIDC parameters):

```
return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
```

If things are implemented properly, the flow will be:

```
Client application -> authorization endpoint -> login page -> Facebook -> external login callback -> authorization endpoint -> client application.
```